# How to serve the View/Action with parameters from different controller without redirecting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to do it? Currently my code is like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        try
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Page", "Content", new { url = "/Home.html" });
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return View();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Not clear what your trying to do.

Comment: What do you want to do? do you want to call action of an other controller?

Comment: Is it unclear? I want to call and return the "Page" action/view of "Content" controller from different controller like "Index" of "Home" controller. Returning View("../Content/Page") should work normally, but this action requires a parameter called "url". RedirectToAction makes my index page looks messy.

Comment: So, finally i understood that, you want to get the returning viewpage of another controller action method to your `Index` method, just because it looks messy

Comment: What do you mean _RedirectToAction makes my index page looks messy_? And why do you have a `try/catch` block (`RedirectToAction()` does not throw an exception.

Comment: We're developing a CMS module for our application and we want to return the default Home/Index view in case of the custom page cannot be found in the database.

@Div No one wants to see their Home/Index URL looks like this right? http://example.com/Content/Page?url=/Home.html

Comment: @StephenMuecke The reason why I have a try-catch block there is because the "Page" view throws a 404 error in case the passed "url" parameter does not exists in the database.

Comment: Its supposed to do that! (do not use a try/catch)

Comment: IMHO 404 error should handled with HTTP response status code handler (e.g. `Response.StatusCode`), not by throwing server-side exception. You can use if-else condition to check returned status code response.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Just tried, it doesn't able to show the default View in case the redirected page runs into an error. Anyway, redirect isn't supposed to be the solution in my question. I just want to call and return the result of an action from a different controller, then display the default view in case of an error was encountered.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto will keep that in mind. As of now, my goal is just to return the result of an action from a different controller, in case of an error, I'll just have to display the default view. Don't question me regarding why I'm doing this, this is the request of the stakeholder, not my decision. Thanks!

Comment: You test that the `url` exists in the database, and if not then return the view (not by using a try/catch)

Comment: @StephenMuecke will change it later once I found a proper way to reach my goal. So I'll leave it right now because it will be overridden later. It is a waste of time to change it immediately without definite solution with what I need to display. Thank you.